# Using Python, making my buttons update a count

Tags: python

Can someone please point me towards the logic to figure out how to count all of my button clicks into a label and update that count? Here is what I have so far. I can't in my mind figure out how to tell it what I want while maintaining the other commands. Here is the text I have so far:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

tP = 0

def mBall():
    mtext = 'Ball'
    mtext1 = 'Total Pitches: ' + str(int(tP + 1))
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text = mtext).grid(sticky = W)
    mlabel3 = Label(mGui, text = mtext1).grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W)

def mStrike():
    mtext = 'Strike'
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text = mtext).grid(sticky = W)

def mFoul():
    mtext = 'Foul'
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text = mtext).grid(sticky = W)

def mInPlay():
    mtext = '*  ' + ment.get()
    mtext1 = 'Total Pitches: 0'
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text = mtext).grid(sticky = W)
    mlabel3 = Label(mGui, text = mtext1).grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W)

    return tP = tP + 1

mGui = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

mGui.geometry('250x450+500+300')
mGui.title('My Copy')

mlabel = Label(mGui, text = 'Pitch Counter').grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)

mlabel = Label(mGui, text = 'r2').grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)
mlabel = Label(mGui, text = 'r4').grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)

mBall = Button(mGui, text = 'Ball', command = mBall, fg = 'white', bg = 'blue').grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
mStrike = Button(mGui, text = 'Strike', command = mStrike, fg = 'white', bg = 'blue').grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)
mFoul = Button(mGui, text = 'Foul', command = mFoul, fg = 'white', bg = 'blue').grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = E)

mInPlay = Button(mGui, text = 'In Play', command = mInPlay, fg = 'white', bg = 'blue').grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)
mEntry = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment).grid()
```

Comment: Just FYI here, but every time you do `name = Widget().grid()`, the `name` ends up pointing to `None`, because that's what geometry management methods return.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, those with *.grid() are meant to stack at the bottom of the grid for now.

Comment: Please correct your indentations. Its hard to read the code.